# spring data i want to use hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, session, spring-data-jpa

i write class to fetch data using hibernate query. when i get Session from EntityManager using

```
Session session=null;
    sessionFactory=entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    session=(Session) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

or

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
```

and session agin asking cast the session into EntityManager

```
public class BranchCustomRepositoryImpl implements BranchCustomRepository{

     @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    public Branch findByOrgOrgIdAndBranchId(String orgId, String branchId) {
    //Session session=null;
    //sessionFactory=entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    //session=(Session) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        System.out.println("BranchCustomRepositoryImpl");
        Long orgId2=Long.valueOf(orgId);
        Long branchId2=Long.valueOf(branchId);
        try{
        Query query=  (Query)((EntityManager) session).createQuery("from Branch b where b.org.orgId=:orgId AND b.branchId=:branchId");      
        query.setParameter("orgId", orgId2);
        query.setParameter("branchId", branchId2);      
        return (Branch) query.uniqueResult();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception"+e.toString());
        }finally{
            try {
                if(session!=null){
                session.close();
                System.out.println("session closed");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

it getting error like,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

if any one know how to use hibernate query in spring data jpa please help me

Comment: You have a query that is perfectly expressable using JPQL so no need to use "Hibernate API"

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of persistent attribute orgId2 is Long, the corresponding
type argument should also be Long while creating the ParameterExpression. And consequently, because type of the ParameterExpression is Long, type of the parameter's value should also be Long as well. So do the following change when you setting query parameters.

Instead of your current lines such as below

```
    query.setParameter("orgId", orgId2);
    query.setParameter("branchId", branchId2);
```

Change it like below

```
    query.setParameter("orgId", Long.valueOf(orgId2));
    query.setParameter("branchId", Long.valueOf(branchId2));
```